# Смещение одного из пунктов навигационного меню

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, меню

Ребят, столкнулся с проблемой. Когда присваиваю последнему элементу списка "Contact" (`li: nth-child(5)` в этом случае) границу, то он смещается. Нужно, чтобы он был на одном уровне с другими элементами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
html,
body,
h1,
.menu {
  font-family: 'Gamja Flower', cursive;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: url(Layer1.png) no-repeat center top / cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1200px;
}

header h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 13.875rem;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-left: 5rem;
}

.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.menu li:nth-child(5) {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.captions {
  margin-top: 15rem;
}

.main-caption {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 8.25rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0.5;
}

header p {
  text-align: center;
  color: #a2a1a1;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  background-color: #50007d;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 12.8125rem;
  margin: 4rem auto;
}

.mouse-icon {
  margin-left: 41.25rem;
  margin-top: 23.125rem;
}

.caption-under-mouse-icon {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <h1><b>Interactive</b>Agency</h1>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Offer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="captions">
    <h3 class="main-caption">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h1>
      <p>Nunc vel nibh tempor, pharetra lectus congue, luctus orci.</p>
      <a href="#" class="button">Ask for price</a>
  </div>
  <img class="mouse-icon" src="icon.png">
  <p class="caption-under-mouse-icon">scroll down</p>
</header>
```

Comment: Не помогло, к сожалению.

Comment: Может в `.menu ` прописать `align-items:center;`

Comment: Спасибо, @Frog , Ваш вариант помог!

Answer (score 2):

```css
html,
body,
h1,
.menu {
  font-family: 'Gamja Flower', cursive;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: url(Layer1.png) no-repeat center top / cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1200px;
}

header h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.menu li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.menu li:nth-child(5) {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.captions {
  margin-top: 15rem;
}

.main-caption {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 8.25rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0.5;
}

header p {
  text-align: center;
  color: #a2a1a1;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  background-color: #50007d;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 12.8125rem;
  margin: 4rem auto;
}

.mouse-icon {
  margin-left: 41.25rem;
  margin-top: 23.125rem;
}

.caption-under-mouse-icon {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <h1><b>Interactive</b>Agency</h1>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Offer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="captions">
      <h3 class="main-caption">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h1>
        <p>Nunc vel nibh tempor, pharetra lectus congue, luctus orci.</p>
        <a href="#" class="button">Ask for price</a>
    </div>
    <img class="mouse-icon" src="icon.png">
    <p class="caption-under-mouse-icon">scroll down</p>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не использовать свойства

```
border: 1px solid transparent;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 15px;
```

Для всех `li`, и пятому элементу уже выставлять

```
border-color: black;
```

???